# Rails, webpacker: where/when to use the import statement in classes, and what's the purpose of requiring in the pack/application.js?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm upgrading an older application to Rails 6, which uses `webpacker` for all the JS asset management.

I'm using the `pikaday` calendar library, and have added it via `yarn add pikaday`, verified it shows up in `packages.json` and then added it to my `app/javascript/packs/application.js` via `require("pikaday")`.

I have a JS class called `Datepicker` that I'm using to abstract the actual `pikaday` calendar.  I'm doing this because I may someday change the datepicker implementation, and this way I'll only have to change a single class instead of update all my `pikaday` calls.

However, it doesn't seem to matter if I `require("pikaday")` in the `application.js` pack file or not; as long as I `import Pikaday from "pikaday"` in the class I'm referencing it in, it makes no difference.

**Questions**

I'm trying to gain understanding of what's going on.

1. Do I need to add `require("pikaday")` or `import Pikaday from "pikaday"` in the `app/javascript/pack/application.js` file?  Why or why not?
2. I'm familiar with the principle that globals are bad and should be avoided, but is there a way to avoid having to `import CLASS from "class_file"` on every JS file that references it?  In my example I want to use the `Datepicker` class in multiple places.  The reason I ask is because I have 10+ classes like this, and it's a little annoying to have 10+ `import` statements at the top of every JS file that I want to use these in. There are certain classes that I always want access to. I've played with the webpacker ProvidePlugin functionality, but it complains that `Datepicker` is not a constructor, so I'm probably missing something but I don't have enough knowledge to know what.

## app/javascript/custom/datepicker.js

```
import Pikaday from "pikaday"

export default class Datepicker {
  constructor(element, options) {
    if (options == null) { options = {} }

    // Store DOM element for reference
    this.element = element

    // Do not re-run on elements that already have datepickers
    if (this.element.datepicker === undefined) {
      options = Object.assign({},
        this.defaultOptions(),
        options
      )

      const picker = new Pikaday(options)

      // Store picker on element for reference
      this.element.datepicker = picker

      return picker
    } else {
      console.log("Datepicker already attached")
      return
    }
  }

  // Overridden by `options` in constructor
  defaultOptions() {
    return {
      field: this.element,
      format: "M/D/YYYY",
      bound: true,
      keyboardInput: false,
      showDaysInNextAndPreviousMonths: true
    }
  }
}
```

## app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()

require("moment")

// Note: if using `@rails/ujs`, you do not need to use `jquery-ujs`.
import "jquery"

// Does not matter if I require this or not, as long as it is imported in the
// class file, I can remove this require statement and everything still works.
require("pikaday")

// StimulusJS
// Webpack's `require` looks for `controllers/index.js` by default
require("controllers")

require("custom/datepicker")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked a couple questions:

1. You only need `import Pikaday from 'pikaday'` in the file where you reference the imported variable, `Pikaday`. In this case, you only need this import in your custom datepicker module. You can remove `require("pikaday")` from your application.js pack file.

   The reason for this is Webpack will take your application.js pack as an entry point to a *dependency graph*; starting there, it will recursively traverse each required/imported module, find the dependencies of those modules, and so on, until all declared modules are included in the bundle. Since you have declared `import 'custom/datepicker'` in the application.js pack, and the custom datepicker imports `pikaday`, it will get included in the bundle as dependency.
2. Your custom `Datepicker` gets compiled as an ES module (rather, Webpack's implementation of ES module), since you are using the ES module syntax `export default ...`. This is important to the way ProvidePlugin works. From the [Webpack 4 documentation of `ProvidePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/):

   > For importing the default export of an ES2015 module, you have to specify the default property of module.

   This means your Webpack configuration for the plugin entry for `Datepicker` would look something like this (using the Rails Webpacker environment api):

   ```js
   const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
   const webpack = require('webpack')
   const {resolve} = require('path');

   environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     Datepicker: [resolve('app/javascript/custom/datepicker'), 'default']
   }))

   module.exports = environment
   ```

   *Opinion*: That said, I encourage you to make your imports explicit, e.g. `import Datepicker from 'custom/datepicker'` in each module where `Datepicker` is referenced. Even if repetitive, it will become much easier to integrate with tools like ESlint, which, with certain code editors, can provide inline feedback about errors from compilation—much easier to setup with explicit dependencies declared in each module.

I put together a working demo of Pikaday using your custom Datepicker with the ProvidePlugin here: https://github.com/rossta/rails6-webpacker-demo/commit/be3d20107c2b19baa8b9560bce05e0559f90086d

Comment: thanks for the details response and repo, much appreciated! I have a quick followup question.  When using the asset pipeline in Rails, it seemed it just combined all the separate JS files into a single large file, such that if I define `class Datepicker {...}` earlier in the file I could reference it globally later in the file.  When webpack combines all the JS into a single pack, does it not do the same thing? Shouldn't I be able to reference classes defined previously?  I'm trying to understand what's going on beyond just copy/paste working solutions.

Comment: The short answer is no, Webpack is not like Sprockets in that regard. Exports bundled by Webpack are not available in the global scope by default. Webpack treats everything as a module. This is better for many reasons. For more on what that means: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc/. For more on the differences between Sprockets and Webpack: https://youtu.be/fKOq5_2qj54.

Comment: The video was extremely helpful!  You shed light on a lot of my own pain points. Sprockets and webpacker are 2 very different approaches to the same problem. I'm going to need to do some more digging and probably refactoring of my JS code as I switch to webpacker.  Thanks!